# Have a listbox inside a richtext box

Tags: c#, tabs, listbox, richtextbox

I have a form with a button and a tabcontrol. If I click on the button, it adds a new tab with a listbox inside the richtextbox of the tabcontrol, but once I move through the tabs, the listbox is only visibile/available on the newest tab and not in the previous tabs. Anyway ideas on how to fix this please? Below is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.Visible == false)
    {
       tabControl1.Visible = true;
       listBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    TabPage tp = new TabPage();
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    int tc = (tabControl1.TabCount + 1);

    rtb.Controls.Add(listBox1);
    tp.Text = "New " + tc.ToString();
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
    return;           
}
```

Comment: Huh? Why would the listbox be visible anywhere else than where you have added it???

Comment: I want the listbox to be added to each richtextbox of the tabcontrol on the button click. Currently the listbox gets added the the newest tab/richtextbox, but when I cycle back to any of the older/previous tabs, the listbox is gone.

Comment: Of course, as you only __have one__ ListBox. You can code the SelectionIndexChanged event an move the ListBox to the RTB of the Selected TabPage.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is adding the same listbox to the new richtextbox you are creating; when the last added richtextbox is hidden (by moving to a different tab), the listbox is also hidden. You have two options:

1. Create a listbox for each richtextbox
2. Handle the selection change for the tab control and reattach the listbox to the currently visible richtextbox.